# Selenium Python Linux headless chrome driver becomes unreachable with too many tabs open

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I'm on an AWS EC2 instance running my headless chrome driver but as soon as I add 8 or so tabs the driver becomes "Unreachable". This doesn't happen on MAC or and htop tells me the driver becomes unreachable when we still have like 6GB of ram left to eat through.

The difference in setup is the virtual display you need for Linux so i'm wondering if there is an allocated memory I need to bump up or some other setting which is causing problems?

The sucky thing is I don't have a Linux machine and can't see whats happening through the instance so it's difficult to diagnose whats happening, any tips on how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Share the relevant HTML and your code trials

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that docker by default only gives 64MB to the SHM filesystem and chrome will crash with no logger messages.

If you increase this filesystem size it works as intended:

```
    sudo docker run  --shm-size 1G -it container /bin/bash
```